# Get the matched attribute of an AngularJS Filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a very typical Angular `ng-repeat` setup like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search" />
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

It works as expected - as text is entered in the search box, any items which have any nested attributes that match the search query are displayed in the list.

My question is how to know *which* attribute of each filtered item was matched by the filter?

Comment: Here in your case I am assuming your data is array/json with String. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for string: The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All strings or objects with string properties in array that match this string will be returned. This also applies to nested object properties.

Comment: Thanks pondy, but I'm trying to find out which of the matched properties on each object were matched. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you set a string as filter, it will search for the entire string inside the object. If you want to filter by property, you can use a object:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search">
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {property: search}">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to filter by any specific property - I want to filter by all properties as normal. What I'm trying to do though is to get the property or properties that were matched for each object matched.

Comment: For example, if each object in the list had a Town property and Country property, and I type something into our filter box, and the list gets filtered, I'd like to know for each item in the filtered list whether my search string matched the Town or the Country property.